Why does ligature look different in VS Code after upgrading Ubuntu?
I have been using VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04 with cascadia code with ligature. I'm particularly fond of the ligature rendering for "==" and "->" where the two equal signs are connected into a long one and the arrow was shorter and sharper:

Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 and they are rendered differently:

Back when I was using Ubuntu 20.04 I also noticed that CLion renders ligature like this as well. What's going on and how do I get the rendering I prefer on the new system?
